# Maximum Value in pandas dataframe in specific column from index to index

Tags: pandas, max

ich have a pandas dataframe pd_data and want to find the maximum value from an index to another index in one specific column.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    Open        High        Low         Close       Volume
0   1.21223     1.21246     1.21215     1.21227     132.32
1   1.21223     1.21226     1.21206     1.21215     200.66
2   1.21215     1.21222     1.21201     1.21204     165.59
3   1.21204     1.21217     1.21204     1.21207     32.89
4   1.21208     1.21208     1.21197     1.21201     135.67
```

I want to finde the maximum value from line 1 to 3 in column 'High'.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```py
out = df.loc[1:4, 'High'].max()
# or
out = df['High'].iloc[1:4].max()
```

```
print(out)

1.21226
```